# In a Google Cloud Identity account, Free edition, unable to activate storage in Google Drive

Tags: google-cloud-identity

I've created recently a free [Google Cloud Identity](https://cloud.google.com/identity) account (free edition) for my organization to manage all Google related services (Firebase, Google Cloud). We have emails hosted elsewhere so I'm not interested in Gmail. However, I would like to use the free GDrive (limited to 15Gb) which is supposed to be supported by Cloud Identiy Free edition as stated [here](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7319251?hl=en):

> Cloud Identity Free edition includes core identity and endpoint management services. It provides managed Google Accounts to users who don’t need certain Google Workspace services, such as Gmail and Google Calendar. However, users can access Google Drive, Docs, Sheets, Slides, Keep, and Meet. You can use Cloud Identity accounts with other Google services, such as Google Cloud, Chrome, Android enterprise, and many third-party applications.

The problem is, in Google Drive, it displays as zero storage available:

> Organisation storage full … Your organisation exceeded its 0 bytes of Google Workspace storage. To continue, either free up space or talk to your administrator.

[image: Gdrive]

### What I've done so far

I've activated the GDrive in Cloud Identity admin UI as:

[image: App enabled]

and in the storage, I've configured also:

[image: Storage]
and
[image: Storage config]

Do you know what could be wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Google Workspace License for those users to have Drive storage allocated to them. Without the license, they can be shared on docs from other organizations and customers, but not the other way around.

See https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120?hl=en for more info on the removal of free services for company emails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error on your configuration and Google Cloud Identity should have 15 Gb of storage available for the user. I think the error message is generated by the pooled storage for Google Workspace users. Sometimes when you do changes on the Google Admin console like enable services or add or cancel subscriptions their system can take time to accept the changes. Try uploading files to the Google Drive of those users its possible this is an aesthetic error that will eventually disappear. A similar situation like when you delete files from Gmail or Google Drive and you still can see a warning that says that you reach your limit of storage.